# Tap events not fired in mgwt

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, mgwt

I have just started learning [mgwt](http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/). After creating a `Button` and adding a `TapHandler`, the tap events are not fired. I don't know what is wrong in the code. I have deployed this on GAE and accessing the site on a Android device. Below is the code for `onModuleLoad()`

```
import com.citrix.demo.client.css.AppBundle;
import com.google.gwt.activity.shared.ActivityMapper;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.StyleInjector;
import com.google.gwt.place.shared.PlaceHistoryHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SimplePanel;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.dom.client.event.tap.TapEvent;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.dom.client.event.tap.TapHandler;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.mvp.client.AnimatableDisplay;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.mvp.client.AnimatingActivityManager;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.mvp.client.Animation;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.mvp.client.AnimationMapper;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.MGWT;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.MGWTSettings;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.MGWTStyle;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.animation.AnimationHelper;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.dialog.TabletPortraitOverlay;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.layout.MasterRegionHandler;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.layout.OrientationRegionHandler;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.widget.Button;
import com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.widget.LayoutPanel;

/**
 * @author Daniel Kurka
 * 
 */
public class MgwtAppEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {
    private static LayoutPanel layout = new LayoutPanel();

    private void start() {

        //set viewport and other settings for mobile
        MGWT.applySettings(MGWTSettings.getAppSetting());
        final ClientFactory clientFactory = new ClientFactoryImpl();

        // Start PlaceHistoryHandler with our PlaceHistoryMapper
        AppPlaceHistoryMapper historyMapper = GWT.create(AppPlaceHistoryMapper.class);
        final PlaceHistoryHandler historyHandler = new PlaceHistoryHandler(historyMapper);

        historyHandler.register(clientFactory.getPlaceController(), clientFactory.getEventBus(), new com.citrix.demo.client.activities.HomePlace());

        if ((MGWT.getOsDetection().isTablet())) {
            // very nasty workaround because GWT does not correctly support
            // @media
            StyleInjector.inject(AppBundle.INSTANCE.css().getText());

            createTabletDisplay(clientFactory);
        } else {
            createPhoneDisplay(clientFactory);

        }
        historyHandler.handleCurrentHistory();

    }

    private void createPhoneDisplay(ClientFactory clientFactory) {

        AnimatableDisplay display = GWT.create(AnimatableDisplay.class);
        PhoneActivityMapper appActivityMapper = new PhoneActivityMapper(clientFactory);
        PhoneAnimationMapper appAnimationMapper = new PhoneAnimationMapper();
        AnimatingActivityManager activityManager = new AnimatingActivityManager(appActivityMapper, appAnimationMapper, clientFactory.getEventBus());
        activityManager.setDisplay(display);
        RootPanel.get().add(display);
    }

    private void createTabletDisplay(ClientFactory clientFactory) {

        SimplePanel navContainer = new SimplePanel();
        navContainer.getElement().setId("nav");
        navContainer.getElement().addClassName("landscapeonly");
        AnimatableDisplay navDisplay = GWT.create(AnimatableDisplay.class);
        final TabletPortraitOverlay tabletPortraitOverlay = new TabletPortraitOverlay();
        new OrientationRegionHandler(navContainer, tabletPortraitOverlay, navDisplay);
        new MasterRegionHandler(clientFactory.getEventBus(), "nav", tabletPortraitOverlay);
        ActivityMapper navActivityMapper = new TabletNavActivityMapper(clientFactory);
        AnimationMapper navAnimationMapper = new TabletNavAnimationMapper();
        AnimatingActivityManager navActivityManager = new AnimatingActivityManager(navActivityMapper, navAnimationMapper, clientFactory.getEventBus());
        navActivityManager.setDisplay(navDisplay);
        RootPanel.get().add(navContainer);

        SimplePanel mainContainer = new SimplePanel();
        mainContainer.getElement().setId("main");
        AnimatableDisplay mainDisplay = GWT.create(AnimatableDisplay.class);
        TabletMainActivityMapper tabletMainActivityMapper = new TabletMainActivityMapper(clientFactory);
        AnimationMapper tabletMainAnimationMapper = new TabletMainAnimationMapper();
        AnimatingActivityManager mainActivityManager = new AnimatingActivityManager(tabletMainActivityMapper, tabletMainAnimationMapper, clientFactory.getEventBus());
        mainActivityManager.setDisplay(mainDisplay);
        mainContainer.setWidget(mainDisplay);
        RootPanel.get().add(mainContainer);

    }

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
                Window.alert("uncaught: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        new Timer() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                start();
            }
        }.schedule(1);

        //set viewport and other settings for mobile
        MGWT.applySettings(MGWTSettings.getAppSetting());
        MGWTStyle.getTheme().getMGWTClientBundle().getMainCss().ensureInjected();
        Label label = new Label("Welcome");
        label.setAutoHorizontalAlignment(Label.ALIGN_CENTER);
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setRound(true);
        button.setText("Click");
        button.addTapHandler(new TapHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onTap(TapEvent event) {
                Window.alert("Hola !");             
            }
        });

        layout.add(label);
        layout.add(button);
        //build animation helper and attach it
        AnimationHelper animationHelper = new AnimationHelper();
//      RootPanel.get().add(layout);
        RootPanel.get().add(animationHelper);
        animationHelper.goTo(layout, Animation.POP);
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me out with this ? Thanks..!

Comment: What type is layout and why are you adding it to the rootPanel, instead of just using the AnimationHelper?

Comment: The layout is `com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.widget.LayoutPanel`. I tried without adding it to the `rootPanel`, but in vain.

Comment: could you update your code sample to show your complete code so that we can figure out whats wrong with the code?

Comment: I have updated the code, this is the complete code for that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding more than one AnimatableDisplays to one region. Those will overlap.

You just added some lines of code to the mgwt showcase I guess without removing the showcase code. To fix this you could remove the call to start() from the timer.